# What resources will be impossible to acquire when structures are disabled?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm considering starting a map with the structures option disabled since I don't really like the villages and the abandoned mine shafts. The mine shafts especially, seems to take over all underground areas to a point where it is hard to find any natural cave systems.

I also realized that ravines, which I like a lot, will still be generated when structures are disabled.

The one resource I know I will miss are melons but giving 1 melon seed as server admin should fix that.

So what other resources of importance will be impossible to find when structures are disabled?

Comment: Stone Brick, Mossy Stone Brick, I think thats it.

Comment: Nope, you can still get those.

Comment: @Bogdacutu How so? AFAIK, mossy Stone Bricks are only generated with the world.

Comment: Fun fact: I just found some Nether Ruins with structures turned off. Also, the text below the structures option specifically mentions dungeons, and those are definitely still generated. Something tells me I'll have to go over my answer again at some point. Damn pre-releases...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Abandoned mine shafts

- As you said, Melon Seeds will be unavailable.

#### Strongholds

- The cracked and mossy variants of Stone Bricks will be unavailable as a building material; normal Stone Bricks can be crafted.
- Ender portal frames will be unavailable, and with it the "The End" dimension
- Red Apple

#### Nether ruins

- Nether Brick
- Nether Brick Fence
- Nether Brick Stairs
- Nether Wart
- Blaze Rod (as Blazes only spawn around the ruins), and all the derivatives.

Comment: Do Dungeons count as Structures?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I think so... If not, they should.

Comment: In 1.9 Pre you can get pumpkin seeds from pumpkins... and old style dungeons are still generated even if structures are off. Nether warts should be possible to farm according to the wiki so giving one as admin should be enough. The main problem I see then is this new gate. Can you construct that one in creative/admin mode?

Comment: @Omokoii You can't obtain the portal frame item as a Creative player (at least not yet), but a server op should be able to spawn them in (ID's #120 decimal). And that old-style dungeons thing is *probably* an oversight, if true.

Comment: @lunboks I quite like the old dungeons though, so for me it is almost perfect the way this setting currently works. The best would still be an option for each feature I guess. Since there seems to be workarounds for most of the missing stuff I will try to go without structures for now.

Comment: The old dungeons are *soooo* much smaller than the Mines / Strongholds / Nether Ruins, though. One room.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer♦ That's why I like them, they are not intrusive. Just a rare small room with some nasties and goodies ^^

Comment: You can get cracked stone brick by making stone brick, placing it and mining it again.